# Is there a way to remove null characters(not the white space)from string?

Tags: string, null, character

I created a character array `char ab[50];` in java to store names using 1 character at a time. Then I converted the array to string using the constructor `String t=new String(ab);`

But if the name is of say 40 characters then the last 10 characters would be `000` so on.Any ideas how to get only the name??

No problem guys i fixed it

Comment: Might want to at least say what language you are using?

Comment: First, please add a tag indicating which language you're using. Second, show us a small complete program that illustrates the problem (it shouldn't need to be more than half a dozen lines or so) -- and tell us how you know the last 10 characters are `000`.

Answer (score 0):

You might initialize your array by filling it with zero.